# VSTS Hosted agent deployment to on-premises using webdeploy

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using VSTS hosted agent to deploy a web deployment package to a server in the corporate network using Web Deploy. However we don't want the port (8172) to be open to every one. Is there any reference which provides the list of IP addresses used by VSTS hosted agents so that we can restrict the access to these IPs only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSTS Hosted agent is in the cloud and the IP is dynamic, there is not changeless IP range.

There is the user voice that you can vote and follow up: [Static IP address for Hosted (Build) Agents in Visual Studio Team Services](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/11004678-static-ip-address-for-hosted-build-agents-in-vis)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use a Private Agent instead? This is how we got around the problem. Builds and Releases are performed on one of our servers, within the corporate network, by a Private Agent.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/agents

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we want to use hosted agent only

Comment: This is also what we did, and it was super easy to setup.  Currently we use a mix of both Hosted and Private agents and split work between them depending on what work needs to be done